# Check first radiobutton using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to check the first radiobutton element in PHP. The radiobuttons are populated from a MySQL database.

```
<?php
echo('<ul id="radio" class="input-list">');
     $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT name, price FROM cases ORDER BY price");
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->bind_result($case_name, $case_price);
     $isFirst = true;
     while($stmt->fetch()) {
         echo '<li>
        <input class="selectedoptions" id="'.$case_name.'" name="config-case" value="'.$case_price.'" type="radio"'.$isFirst?' checked':''.' onchange="updateImage(this.id);">
        <label class="sub-label" for="'.$case_name.'">'.$case_name.' [£'.$case_price.']</label>
        </li>';
        $isFirst = false;
     }
     $stmt->close();
?>
```

This outputs "checked" for each row, as opposed to the radiobutton and label. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose your ternary operation in parenthesis to evaluate it first.

```
.... . ($isFirst ? ' checked' : '') . ...
```

Otherwise the concatenation operations take precedence.